# SQL Server 2012 - error in MERGE statement on semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL statement with MERGE. It works fine when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, however when I am trying my application to call the exact same query via a scheduled task and execute it, I see the below error.

Can someone please help me understand whats happening.

```
MERGE TEST2 AS TARGET       
USING TEST1 AS SOURCE    
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
AND SOURCE.ID IS NOT NULL  
WHEN MATCHED THEN                           
    UPDATE SET ID=SOURCE.ID,
               Name= SOURCE.Name,
               City= SOURCE.City,
               State = SOURCE.State

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ID, Name, City, State)
VALUES(SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.Name, SOURCE.City, SOURCE.State);
```

---

> Message: java.sql.SQLException: A MERGE statement must be terminated
>   by a semi-colon (;).

Comment: How is your scheduled task executing? Apparently through some Java code? Double check you're not running into some kind of length restriction where only part of the statement is getting passed to the server.

Comment: Looks like its executing through some java code, but theres no restriction on the length of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs in SSMS and not trough the application with that particular error means that SQL does not get a semicolon. Why that is happening? Run a profiler to see what your application sends to SQL. My wild guess would be that your application cuts the tail of your query. For instance following query will generate the same error:

```
MERGE TEST2 AS TARGET       
USING TEST1 AS SOURCE    
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
AND SOURCE.ID IS NOT NULL  
WHEN MATCHED THEN                           
    UPDATE SET ID=SOURC
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `DataConnect` mode (i.e. outside of SQL Server Management Studio) to execute a SQL statement, the semi-colon characters *may be* automatically removed as the engine interprets them as the end of the statement. This is generally not an issue, but if a `MERGE` statement is used, it can lead to the error message **"SQL Error (10713): MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;)."**

To avoid this, the semi-colon must be escaped with a **back-slash**. For example:

```
MERGE TEST2 AS TARGET       
USING TEST1 AS SOURCE    
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
AND SOURCE.ID IS NOT NULL  
WHEN MATCHED THEN                           
    UPDATE SET ID=SOURCE.ID,
               Name= SOURCE.Name,
               City= SOURCE.City,
               State = SOURCE.State

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ID, Name, City, State)
VALUES(SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.Name, SOURCE.City, SOURCE.State)\;
```